# Inverse trigonometric question including geometric sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, geometric-progressions

> $x_1,x_2$ are two positive values of $x$ for which $2 \cos x$, $|\cos x|$ and $(3\sin^2x-2)$ are in geometric sequence. One possible value of $|x_1-x_2|$ can be equal to
>
> a) $\frac{2\pi}{3}$
> b) $\frac{\pi}{3}$
> c) $2\cos^{-1}(\frac{2}{3})$
> d) $\cos^{-1}(\frac{2}{3})$

Since $2 \cos x$, $|\cos x|$ and $(3\sin^2x-2)$ are in geometric progression, therefore,$$|\cos x|^2 = 2\cos x (3\sin^2x-2) .$$

The right hand side is:$$2\cos x(3(1-\cos^2x)-2) = 6\cos x - 6\cos^3x-4\cos x .$$

So
\begin{gather*}
\cos x = 6-6\cos^2x-4 = 2-6\cos^2x\\
\Rightarrow \quad 6\cos^2x-\cos x-2=0
\end{gather*}

Therefore,
\begin{gather*}
\cos x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1+24}}{12}\\
\Rightarrow \quad \cos x = \frac{1}{2}, \; \frac{-1}{3}
\end{gather*}

Please guide further....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were on the right track, there was just a small mistake. I understand the problem as follows:

$$2\cos(x)=a,\quad |\cos(x)|=ar,\quad 3\sin^2(x)-2=ar^2$$

We get
$$r=\frac{|\cos(x)|}{2\cos(x)}=\pm \frac{1}{2}$$
and consequently
$$3\sin^2(x)-2 = 1-3\cos^2(x) = \frac{a}{4} = \frac{1}{2}\cos(x)$$

which gives

$$6\cos^2(x) + \cos(x) - 2 = 0$$

with the solutions

$$\cos(x) = \{\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{2}{3} \}$$

Comment: But answer options are different could u please elaborate further...

Comment: So you still have to find $|x_1-x_2|$ when $\cos x_1=1/2$ and $\cos x_2=-2/3$, but presumably you know how to find the values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ that give you those cosines.